# Can IWindsorContainer be instantiated through a static method?

Tags: thread-safety, castle-windsor, static-members

I'm still groping around a bit with Castle Windsor. At the moment all my pages which need an IWindsorContainer instantiate one themselves through a property:

```
private IWindsorContainer WindsorContainer
  {
    get
    {
      if (_windsorContainer == null)
      {
        _windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(Server.MapPath("~/CastleWindsorConfiguration.xml")));
      }
      return _windsorContainer;
    }
  }
```

I'm getting a little tired of copying and pasting this property and the backing field from page to page! Also I don't really understand the life cycle of the IWindsorContainer.

I'd much rather get one of these through a static property of some class, but does anyone know if I can consider it threadsafe? How do you guys work with IWindsorContainer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard and recommended practice is to have **one instance of the container per application**.

See these related questions for further information:

- [Usage of IoC Containers; specifically Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367178/usage-of-ioc-containers-specifically-windsor)
- [How to get instance of service in Windsor Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694778/how-to-get-instance-of-service-in-windsor-castle)

And yes, Windsor is thread-safe.

Comment: Static method here we go! That's all I needed to know - thanks.